# Is Puncture a suitable synonym for Patch?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

In [What should I put in a bicycle emergency patch kit for situations more severe than a common puncture?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/84532/what-should-i-put-in-a-bicycle-emergency-repair-kit#84532) I see that [user2617804](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/33231/user2617804) points out there is no tag for **Patch**

I was going to add it as a synonym for Puncture, but are there may be times when its a patch for clothing, or an embroidered patch, for metal patch on a frame.

Does Patch need its own tag instead ?

Comment: I wanted patch for temporary fix situations.

Answer (score 4):

I’d argue that no, *patch* doesn’t need a separate tag. In context, we understand that a patch is something you would do to a tube that has punctured. The other use cases mentioned above are not cycling-specific, or else not something you would be able to do on the road side (i.e. applying a metal patch or even a carbon fiber patch).

Comment: As a point of interest, there are actually water-activated fiberglass repair products., which could conceivably be used roadside.

Comment: @MaplePanda that is very interesting, but I might pass on repairing a carbon bike with that product.